# if column not include some word

Tags: google-sheets

if column not include some word

I use this filter but not working:

```
=if(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A6,"boy")),"")
```

But it works if I use just one row like that:

```
=if(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1,"boy")),"")
```

return empty cell

I want to search in hole column A in has text boy and return empty cell

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A6; "boy")); )
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A6; "boy"));;"xxx")
```

if you want to output only true/false then drop the `IF`:

```
=INDEX(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A6; "boy")))
```

or:

```
=FILTER(A1:A6; NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A6; "boy")))
```

Comment: I want to use Filter `=FILTER(A1:A6,NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A6, "boy")))`

Comment: @devlopperjohn yes thats also possible. answer updated

Comment: I want to return empty if not available but not working  `=FILTER(A1:A6,if(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A6, "boy")),"")
`

Comment: @devlopperjohn can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output